# difference between the small and big étale/flat/... site

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, etale-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

What is the difference between the *small* and the *big* étale (or flat or syntomic or ...) site? How does the cohomology vary? When should I use which one? Up to now, I have always used the small sites.

Comment: The have the same cohomology as long as you look at locally constant sheaves. Their geometric properties are rather different, but they are in some sense homotopy equivalent.

Comment: And what about sheaves which are represented by smooth group schemes like $\mathbf{G}_m$ or $\mathscr{A}$ for an Abelian scheme $\mathscr{A}$?

Comment: Should the cohomologies be the same? You can always compute the cohomology as the limit over hypercoverings of the final object. But the hypercoverings of the final object are the same in both categories.

Comment: If the cohomologies are the same, what is the reason for considering different sites?

Comment: Relevant for this discussion: [Tag 03YX](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03YX) (note that the Stacks project does not consider the small fppf site, etc). However, writing down a sheaf on the big site is much harder (this involves a lot more data). I think that therefore sheaves on the big site should have stronger base change properties.

Comment: @Timo The best answer to this question is doubtless the counter question: what do *you* want to use sites for?

Comment: @TimoKeller big sites are useful e.g. when you want to consider schemes as etale (or fppf or ...) sheaves. If $S$ is a scheme, then an $S$-scheme $X$ gives and is determined by its associated sheaf ${\rm Hom}_S(-, X)$ on the big etale site of $S$. So you can define e.g. the Picard scheme by defining the associated sheaf first and then asking whether it is representable. This utterly fails for the small etale site though: take $X\to S$ a closed immersion, then the restriction of ${\rm Hom}_S(-, X)$ to the small etale site will usually be the empty sheaf.

Comment: @Piotr Achinger: Thank you! Why don't you make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 9):

You can always compute the cohomology as the limit over hypercoverings of the final object. But the hypercoverings of the final object are the same in both categories, so it seems that the cohomology is the same (i.e. the cohomology of a sheaf on the big etale site maps isomorphically to the cohomology of its restriction to the small etale site).

Big sites are useful e.g. when you want to consider schemes as etale (or fppf or ...) sheaves. If $S$ is a scheme, then an $S$-scheme $X$
 gives and is determined by its associated sheaf ${\rm Hom}_S(−,X)$
 on the big etale site of $S$. So you can define e.g. the Picard scheme by defining the associated sheaf first and then asking whether it is representable. This utterly fails for the small etale site though: take $X\to S$ a closed immersion, then the restriction of ${\rm Hom}_S(−,X)$
 to the small etale site will usually be the empty sheaf.